# python function passed into another function as argument

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to pragramming and python. This is something like what I have.

```
 Def some_function():
     Print "stuff"

 Def another_function(x):
     running = True
     While running:
         x

another_function(some_function())
```

Why does it only print "stuff" the first time going through the loop?

I read some stuff that talked about late binding but not sure if that is what this is or how to fix it in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't pass the function, you called the function and passed its value. So it printed `stuff` before you ever got into the loop.

To refer to a function without calling it, you leave off the `()`. So it should be:

```
another_function(some_function);
```

Then in `another_function`, you have to call the function:

```
def another_function(x):
    running = True
    while running:
        x()
```